# Unitary Matrix and its product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> Let $A$ $\in$ $\mathbb{M_{3x3}(R)}$ be unitary. Prove that there exists $x$ $\in \mathbb{R^3}$ such that $A^2x$=x.

How should I proceed with this question? I just want a vague idea of how to do it.

Comment: $x=0$ is a trivial answer but you can also get nonzero $x$. Show that $1$ is an eigen value of $A^{2}$ by first looking at eigen values of $A$. A third degree polynomial with real coefficients cannot have all there roots non-real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to showing that $A^{2}$ has 1 as an eigenvalue(assuming you are not actually satisfied with x=0 as a solution, cf the above comment).
In order to prove this you need to know/prove a few preliminary steps:

1. The eigenvalues of a unitary matrix are all complex numbers of **unit modulus**.
2. Since your matrix is real, its characteristic poly has real coefficients and degree 3. The roots of the char poly are the eigenvalues and since the coefficients of the poly are real, **the roots come in pairs** (a,a*) of **complex conjugates**.
3. Since the char poly has 3 roots they cannot all be complex non-real(since they come in pairs by 2.), just by counting. Therefore **your matrix has a real eigenvalues (of modulus 1!)**. This eigenvalue can therefore only be +1 or -1. Eitherway, 1 is an eigenvalue of $A^{2}$

Comment: Can you help me by describing your thought process? I mean what you thought when you saw the problem and how you came to the conclusion that eigenvalues might be needed for this question?

Comment: Hi @Jimmy. The definition of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ for a matrix M over the complex numbers is: a complex number such that there exists a column vector x such that Mx = $\lambda$x so as you can see your problem simply **is** a problem about the eigenvalues of $A^{2}$. x is called an *eigenvector*
The rest of my thought process was merely remembering some facts about unitary matrices.
Maybe you should brush up on some definitions and basic properties in linear algebra and matrices.